# Is there a function to import external file to main file?

Tags: python, external

```
import sys
import os


module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path+"E:\\myfolder")

import myfile
```

Error:

```
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myfile']
```

Comment: Adding to `sys.path` is the right approach. Maybe your path is wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder similar issue. please find it in the above link.

Comment: try `import .myfile` when `.` markes that myfile is in current directory with `main.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're wrong at the `sys.path.append(module_path+"E:\\myfolder")` statement. Because the module path is now the absolute path, You don't need `E:` prefix.

Try again with:

```
sys.path.append(module_path+"\\myfolder")
```

You can check your paths by `print(sys.path)`. It will print all paths that it's looking for the module

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help.I tried sys.path and put it in sys.append.append(). Do i put the mail file path or myfile path? I put the myfile path  is this right ?

Comment: For info the two files are on anaconda jupyter platform.

Comment: @AliNassar No, You just need to put the folder path where contains your modules, in this case the folder containing `myfile` module. I guess you have `myfile.py` inside `myfolder`. I'm right ???